# Swift 2.2 loop through string and get char & index

Tags: string, swift, foreach, swift2

I'm trying to loop through a String get get the characters as well as their index. Sounds easy.. but I'm not finding the correct syntax for doing that.

Here is what I was trying:

```
let str = "testString"
for (index, char) in str.characters  {
    print(index)
    print(char)
}
```

or

```
for (index, char) in enumerate(str.characters)  {...}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let str = "testString"
for (index, element) in str.characters.enumerate() {
    print(index)
    print(element)
}
```

Comment: perfect thanks! I didn't find that in the documentation

Comment: // Swift 3.0 it's now "enumerated()" instead of "enumerate()"

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let str = "Swift 4"
for (index, element) in str.enumerated() {
    print(index)
    print(element)
}
```